# Multiple Laravel apps under one domain

Tags: php, apache, laravel

I'm just getting started with Laravel and have just finished some basic applications. I'm trying to come up with a plan on using Laravel more widespread through our organization. I'm trying to figure out how I can have multiple Laravel installs without having to create a ton of Apache vhosts.

Within our company, we have many departments and each of those departments have a variety of internal and public forms and/or apps. Our website structure is all served by the same instance of Apache on a Linux server and we occasionally use virtual hosts to separate out some specific sections, but not departments (as it would be really overwhelming).  Our structure on the webserver looks something like this:

```
/
/department1/someapp
            /anotherapp
/department2/internalapp
            /anotherform
/department3
...and so on
```

So people basically access it like: www.company.com/department1/someapp etc...We have about 30 different departments which encompass a site of about 52,000 html and php files in a mix of procedural php, javascript, and plain html.

So the issues that I see with multiple installs would yield something like having to access the apps like this:

```
www.company.com/department1/app1/public
                            app2/public
www.company.com/department2/app1/public etc...
```

Obviously vhosts would make this look a lot prettier by just being able to access the apps with department1.company.com or department2.company.com, but we don't want to create that many subdomains. So I'm looking for some better ideas on how to do this.

Comment: It's possible. You could rename the `public` folders to `department1`, etc if you wanted. Then you would need to overwrite all the paths for each application, as you would want to remove the bulk of the app from the web accessible directories for security reasons.

Comment: IMHO you should take the extra work and use subdomains. This would be the most reliable way for doing this. Multiple apps on one DocRoot could quickly become confusing and unmaintainable.

Comment: @jakub_jo it would also become unmaintainable from the standpoint of all the internal and external DNS records that would have to be created along with all the virtual hosts. There should be a way of doing this without having to create tons if sub domains.  Im thinking I can install Laravel in the subdirs and use .htaccess to remove access to the root of the subdir then rewrite to move them into the public folder for each place we have an app.

Comment: Could you use one Laravel base for all the apps? And just separate the behaviour with routes and "modules"?

Comment: @jakub_jo this *might* work but I think I'll have to logically separate out all the department apps and put them under one master folder rather than keeping them in all their separate department folders as they are now.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the [Linux symlinks](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=linux+symlink&atb=v144-1&ia=web) could solve your task. They are cheap an clean way to forward your front end requests to the Linux server folders.

You would want to install as many Laravel (or any other software) instances as needed one per the web service you provide to your departments.

You could have the single good looking entry point, say, `www.mycompany.com` referring to the single `vhost` entry referring to say `/sites` folder on your server.

Then, as soon as you have your Accounting Department Laravel webapp (or site) under `/accounting` folder on the server to access the site with `www.mycompany.com/accounting` address, you have to create the `accounting` symlink in `/sites` folder and this symlink should point at `/accounting/public` folder of yor Laravel app.

Thus you create as many apps as you need and forward requests to them via the respective symlinks in `/sites` folder.

Answer (score 0):

The entry point for a Laravel app is its **index.php** file (https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/public/index.php). So as long as you have a **.htaccess** file passing all requests through this front controller, you can then change the autoload and bootstrap paths to your heart’s content.